# Is it possible to move links or ocr layer from a djvu file to another one?

Tags: djvu, hyperlinking, ocr

I have two similar copies of a text in djvu format:

– one copy has an OCR layer;

– the other copy has various convenient links in the "Contents" and "Subject index" pages, linking to the relevant pages in the text. But this copy doesn't have an OCR layer, and I don't manage to build one (tried the [Any2djvu server](http://any2djvu.djvu.org/ulinit.php) but it doesn't manage to).

Is it possible to somehow extract the links from the second copy and include them in the first? or extract the OCR layer of the first and include it in the second? I know how to move and edit bookmarks between djvu files using `djvused`, but have no idea of how to work with links and OCR layers.

Answer (score 1):

Though you've already solved your djvu problem...
This other old software (DjVuToy) offers: Edit, annotations, import, export, make file, hidden text, move pages, add/delete images, delete/add pages, export layers in pages, etc.
Not sure if it would be an alternate option for any of your other project needs, but for an old program it offers plenty of capability.
[forum web link](https://www.portablefreeware.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=16880)
[french web site where its downloadable](http://www.gratilog.net/xoops/modules/mydownloads/singlefile.php?cid=62&lid=2796)

Comment: Thank you, it's a neat program. From what I see it only runs on Windows, though?

Comment: Yes limited to Windows; sadly no Linux option. Sounds like your Linux command line method is the solution for the time being.

Comment: I'll try DjVuToy through Wine on Linux :)

Answer (score 0):

As usual, `man` comes to rescue.

To extract *annotations* – that's the name of links – present in the djvu file `filename.djvu`, and save them in the file `annotations.dsed`:

```
djvused filename.djvu -e 'output-ant' > annotations.dsed
```

The file `annotations.dsed` can then be edited with a text editor if there's need to modify the links or move/resize the link areas.

The annotations in `annotations.dsed` can then be inserted in the original or a new file `filename2.djvu`:

```
djvused filename2.djvu -f annotations.dsed -s
```

Check `man djvused` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy OCR layer from one DJVU-file to another using [DjvuOCR](https://djvu-info.ru/prog/Djvu.OCR.v2.4b.Rus.zip) program (Extract/Burn OCR layer functionalirty).